# Azure authentication issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

I have a blazor server-side application that uses Azure B2C authentication. Everything works well when I run it on my local machine. Now I deployed it as Azure App Service. The application url is redirected for authentication to https://mycompanyb2c.b2clogin.com/mycompanyb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_myapp_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize... etc.

But immediately after that it is redirected to redirect uri (https://localhost:44333/signin-oidc). I don't know why this happens. What I did notice was a warning "You can use this application to authenticate against Azure Active Directory, but not Azure AD B2C". This surprises me, as I thought the app is under Azure AD B2C, and I can see it under Home/Azure AD B2C on Azure portal.

How can my issue be resolved?

Comment: Look at the chrome dev tools network trace, you’ll find the error in the response of the /authorize endpoint.

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT In Chrome, I don't see any errors. I cannot see the response at all, as it shows "Failed to load response data". When I use Firefox, I see missing favicon.ico: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Do you think this could cause the failure?

Comment: Look at the response headers, the location header probably has the error in it. Favicon has no relevance to the problem.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I don't see location header. The response headers only contain:

   Allow: OPTIONS,TRACE,GET,HEAD,POST

Cache-Control: private

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 1420
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 12:59:39 GMT

Public: OPTIONS,TRACE,GET,HEAD,POST

Set-Cookie: ...
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-Frame-Options: DENY

x-ms-gateway-requestid: ...

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT BTW, just noticed status code is 200 OK. So I don't get why it goes to redirect URI at all, after redirecting to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update the redirect URL in your json file?

Did you update the redirect URL in the app registration?

It looks like this is pointing to your local PC rather than the Azure App Service.

In terms of the message, is your app. one of [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#unsupported-application-types)?

Comment: No, I did not upate redirect uri. What should I point it to? 
But the main question is why it redirects at all, instead of authenticating the user.

Comment: AAD B2C must send a token back to the app so the app understands the user authenticated. To perform that, AAD B2C must know what URL to send that token to, called the redirect uri. Error would be found in the network trace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application